# How to type The Replacement Character (�) from keyboard?

Tags: utf-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, utf-16, uikeyboard

I want to type "The Replacement Character" in my data, how can I type � it from the English keyboard? Is there any shortcut to type it ?

Comment: In Windows: [hold `Alt`, write `+FFFD`, release `Alt`](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602). See also https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm

Comment: MAC: https://www.webnots.com/how-to-use-unicode-hex-input-method-in-mac/

Comment: @JosefZ That approach didn't work for me on Windows 10 (using `echo` from the command prompt). From your link _"Alas, this appears to require a registry setting."_, but even after adding that Registry setting it still didn't work. But `echo �`, where the replacement character is pasted, works fine.

Comment: @Ayush As it stands your question is arguably off topic for Stack Overflow (_"Not about programming or software development"_) and may be closed. Can you update it to explain how it relates to software development? Or consider posting your question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: On SuperUser see [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/47420) and [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/q/13086) Voting to close here since this is off topic for SO, and has already been asked and answered on superuser.